# Neo4j-Import java.long.arrayindexoutofboundsexception: requests index -1 but length is 1000000

Tags: neo4j

We're running Neo4j 2.3.0 M1 on Windows Server 2012 R2 with Java 8.0.45. I consistently encounter the error shown below when calling neo4j-import with 459 tab-separated files, totaling 39GB. If the import had succeeded, the resulting database would have contained around 100 million nodes, 200 million properties, and 800 million relationships.

Neo4jImport.bat succeeds when I call it with 240 tab-separated files totaling 20GB.  When I run the same process with Neo4j 2.2, I don’t even get a response, it just hangs after loading about 6GB into the database files.

If I interpret the error correctly, I’m running into a limitation in the size of an array populated during a sort operation. Does anyone know of a way to work around this limitation?

Error:
Exception in thread “SortWorker-0” java.long.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Requests index -1, but length is 1000000 
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.OffHeapNumberArray.addressOf(OffHeapNumberArray.java:54)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.OffHeapLongArray.get(OffHeapLongArray.java:42)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.FixedLongArray.get(FixedLongArray.java:48)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.ParallelSort.partition(ParallelSort.java:216)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.ParallelSort.recursiveQsort(ParallelSort.java:262)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.ParallelSort.access$500(ParallelSort.java:42)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.ParallelSort.$SirtWorker.run(ParallelSort.java:348)

Comment: Thanks Michael for reporting it, seems like you ran into a bug, I'll report it to our team. Sorry for the inconvenience. How long does the import of the 240 files take?

Comment: Thanks for response. I'd say that the 240 files take 3-4 hours to load, which is more than sufficient for our application.